# How does a noun phrase translate into a verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs, learning

Ok. The whole sentence is:

Person A bandages Person B's arm.

Person B says: ありがとう。ずいぶん慣れた処置ね？看護婦でもやってたの？

I get what the sentences are saying.

But! For the life of me I can't parse ずいぶん慣れた処置ね？ into that makes any sense to me. All I can come up with is: "You do very accustomed treatments." Which I know barely makes any sense (grammatical or otherwise).

Can someone please break this down for me?

Comment: “I get what the sentences are saying.”  Probably not.

Comment: The subtitle says that ずいぶん慣れた処置ね？ means: You're very experienced at this, huh? 

But grammatically getting from the japanese sentence to the english translation is what is giving me problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`慣れる` can also mean "become skilled at", so it's more like "You've become quite skilled at this treatment.  Were you a nurse or something?"  More literally, it would be like "This is a treatment at which you've become quite skilled."  There is a `です` that's omitted before `ね？`; if this wasn't obvious to you, that may be the reason you had trouble with it.  So there's no "**do**" in it as you were thinking.  It's an "**is**".

Comment: Would "experienced with" also be a good/decent translation of nareru?

Comment: I would say so.

Answer (score 4):

`ずいぶん` 'very' is an adverb and an intensifier modifying `慣れた` 'became accustomed'. `ずいぶん慣れた` is a relative clause modifying `処置` 'treatment'. `ずいぶん慣れた処置` is a nominal predicate. Here, its subject is omitted. The copula `だ` is optionally omitted before certain elements including the sentence-final particle `ね`. To reconstruct what is omitted, it would be like this:

> (あなたの処置は)ずいぶん慣れた処置(だ)ね。
>   '(Your treatment) (is) a very accustomed treatment, isn't it?'

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. 

How's this: (You are) very experienced with treatment?"

Comment: What the heck???

Comment: What is your motivation for deleting the answer?

Comment: Please see: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/603/what-to-do-when-a-user-is-destroying-information-on-the-site

Comment: @sawa: please refrain from these (recurrent) post-deletion tantrums. If there is an issue to sort out, feel free to contact an admin...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to add to the already posted answers, except you might be interested in knowing that omitting the だ before ね is mostly female language, and would rarely be used by males.

Of course, this distinction only applies after nouns and na-adjective stems, since verbs and i-adjectives don't have a だ to begin with.

Another sentence ender that this phenomenon occurs for is よ:

> 好きよ！  I like/love you! (mainly female)